# Can't align button to center of div

Tags: html, css, image, button, center

I have been trying to align a certain button to the horizontal center of a div, but unlike all the other buttons I have, this one will not ignore a photo div I have above it and gets pushed off to the side.
[The button I am talking about is the one in the center titled "Learn How"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vaMz.jpg)

```css
.button2 {
  background-color: #E0E5E9;
  border: 1px solid #e76d6a;
  color: #e76d6a;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.button2:hover {
  background-color: #e76d6a;
  /* Orange */
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="page1">
  <div class="page1image">
    <h2>Leadership</h2>
  </div>
  <h3 class="page1head">Our Purpose.</h3>
  <p class="page1content">Simply invest in disruptive ideas and the people behind them. Seed-stage companies aiming to break ground are having difficulty accessing capital in developed markets. Our team is ready to have that discussion and happy to provide thought leadership,
    advising start-ups on how to grow business.</p>
  <button class="button">Let's Talk.</button>
</div>
<div id="page2">
  <h3 class="page2head">Our Ability to Navigate</h3>
  <p class="page2content">Extinguish the 'burn rate' with planned trajectory. 5Lion leverages existing relationships in the U.S. and other mature economies providing real growth to new companies while navigating risk and redefining markets. Traditional integrity meets New Age
    principles.</p>
  <button class="button2">Learn How</button>
</div>
```

I have tried position:absolute, display:block, display:inline-block, width:100%, and all sorts of stuff which had had no effect on it.

I don't see what could be going wrong with the button colliding with the photo div above like in this image.

[The margin of the button collides with the margin of the image above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNnPD.jpg)

I hope it's not a stupidly simple solution that I haven't tried yet.

Comment: Can you include the code for the photo div so we can reproduce the issue? Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can put the `Learn How` button in another div, then set a `margin-left` and `text-align: center` to that `div`

Comment: If you can include the code for the photo div for us reproduce that issue, will be helpful too

Comment: try adding clear:left; on the button class.